# How can we show that "almost surely" equal random variables have the same distribution?

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, random-variables

> How can we show that "almost surely" equal random variables have the same distribution?

We know  $X =\text{(a.s)} Y$. What I have so far:

$$\begin{align*}\implies& P(X = Y) = 1 \\
\implies& P(X(c) = Y(c)) = 1&(\text{for all }c)\\
\implies&P(X \in A) = P(Y \in A),\end{align*}$$
where $A$ is the set $X(c).$

I don't know if I can just make the above statement though. Am I missing something?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: ........ super helpful, thanks man!

Comment: what is meant by "the set $X(c)$". Is $c$ an argument of function $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P(X=Y)=1$ then for any measurable $A$ we have:$$P(X\in A\wedge X\neq Y)\leq P(X\neq Y)=0$$
so that $P(X\in A\wedge X\neq Y)=0$ and consequently:

$$P(X\in A)=P(X\in A\wedge X=Y)+P(X\in A\wedge X\neq Y)=P(X\in A\wedge X=Y)$$

Likewise we also find:$$P(Y\in A)=P(Y\in A\wedge X=Y)$$

This can be applied to find:

$$P(X\in A)=P(X\in A\wedge X=Y)=P(Y\in A\wedge X=Y)=P(Y\in A)$$

---

Your conclusion that $P(X=Y)=1$ should imply that $P(X(c)=Y(c))=1$ for each $c$ is not understood by me. The expression  $P(X(c)=Y(c))$ suggests that $\{X(c)=Y(c)\}$ is an event, i.e. a measurable subset of the domain of $X$ and $Y$. What event are you talking about?

Comment: I would like to ask you about the notation $\wedge$. Does it have the same meaning as $\cap$? Is $P(X\in A\wedge X\ne Y)$ a shorthand for $P(\{X\in A\}\cap \{X\ne Y\})$?

Comment: @V.C. Yes, that's what it means. In fact $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\in A\wedge X(\omega)\neq Y(\omega)\}$ (wich comes to the same as intersection) is the event here.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You know that $X=Y$ on a set $A$ with $P(A)=1$. Now you just need to show that for any $B$ in your sigma algebra, $P(X\in B)=P(Y\in B)$. Since $B$ is somewhat arbitrary, it could contain elements not in $A$. So first prove $P(X\in B)=P(X\in B\cap A)$. Now conclude the result.